# Is it possible to send a "push" notification to a user on your site without requesting permissions?

Tags: html, websocket

We're trying to update a user, without polling, of an event outside of the scope of what they're doing (for instance, a user has liked one of their posts). Traditionally, we've done this via polling or websockets. I know that HTML5 has push notifications, but it's not exactly what we're looking for (we only want to be able to push a "payload" of data, and not a message, and we don't want to push it to a user that's not on the site).

Is this possible in HTML5 without websockets?

Answer (score 0):

Other than WebSockets, which sound like a perfect fit and the older polling approaches, you might consider SSE (Server Sent Events).

However, WebSockets is generally superior to SSE in many ways (reconnection logic aside) and requires less resources from the browser.

I'm not sure what the limitation on WebSockets might be, but your use case is ideal for a WebSocket connection with a pub/sub backend.